# How can I split strings using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have these results from calling a function in javascript:

```
(1, 00), (2, 10), (3, 01), (4, 11)
```

I want to assign that in an array or json format that will result like this:

```
[{id:1, number: 00},{id:2, number: 10},{id:3, number: 01},{id:4, number: 11}]
```

Or anything that will result an array lenght of 4

Is that possible? Please help. Thanks :)

Comment: is the result a string? or what data structure is it? have you tried anything?

Comment: Of course it's possible, you just have to write the program to do it.

Comment: Use `.split()` with a delimiter of `),` to find each pair. Then split that up with a delimiter of `,` to find each number in the pair.

Comment: The result was in string format @NinaScholz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the other splitting solution, you could use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and replace/add the wanted parts for a valid [JSON](http://json.org/) string and use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) for parsing the string for an object, you want.

```js
var data = '(1, 00), (2, 10), (3, 01), (4, 11)',
    json = data.replace(/\(/g, '{"id":').replace(/,\s?(?=\d)/g, ',"number":"').replace(/\)/g, '"}'),
    object = JSON.parse('[' + json + ']');

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use regex to get the pattern and generate the array based on the matched content.

```js
var data = '(1, 00), (2, 10), (3, 01), (4, 11)';

// regex to match the pattern
var reg = /\((\d+),\s?(\d+)\)/g,
  m;
// array for result
var res = [];
// iterate over each match
while (m = reg.exec(data)) {
  // generate and push the object
  res.push({
    id: m[1],
    number: m[2]
  });
}

console.log(res);
```

---

Or by splitting the string.

```js
var data = '(1, 00), (2, 10), (3, 01), (4, 11)';

var res = data
  // remove the last and first char
  .slice(1, -1)
  // split the string
  .split(/\),\s?\(/)
  // iterate over the array to generate result
  .map(function(v) {
    // split the string 
    var val = v.split(/,\s?/);
    // generate the array element
    return {
      id: val[0],
      number: val[1]
    }
  })

console.log(res);
```